# Is the 'find' utility on Windows 7 different than the one on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, batch, find

I have a batch script that I created which works fine on Windows XP but faults on Windows 7.

The script basically finds out what the OS is.

```
wmic os get | find "Windows XP">nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto winxp

wmic os get | find "Windows 7”>nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto win7
```

Thing is, this works fine on Windows XP but not on Windows 7. Windows 7 throws the following error:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

So my question is, was the find utility changed?

Comment: I hope you copy-pasted this.

Comment: Of course. I am testing out the solution mentioned below now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the funny looking double quote.

> wmic os get | find "Windows XP">nul
>   if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto winxp
>
> ::SMART QUOTES FTL
>
> wmic os get | find "Windows 7”>nul 
>   if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto win7

Comment: Yup, smart quotes FTL. Curiously, I have yet to find a text editor that will highlight such errors in batchfiles. Even the Powershell ISE doesn't directly correct or highlight such errors.  All you'll notice is that strings are colored red.

Comment: I use Notepad++ as my batch IDE.

Comment: Yeah, that would be my pick too. I could of sworn there are plugins or scripts that will run right before a save.  I gotta google for that one.